# How to "hold form submission" and go through authentication in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to code a form submission mechanism where if the user would be required to authenticate, but once the user would have authenticated, I would like the form to be submitted automatically without the user having to fill the values again or even just click the button.

For example, the classic case is to post on a blog before being authenticated. Typically the non-logged user will complete the post, click "Post", then being redirected to an authentication page and once he is authenticated he will not need to go back and fill the post and click "Post" again.

What is the right approach to implement this in Play?

- Shall one store the form data in the session before redirecting to authentication?
- And maybe in the authentication page store a reference to the action which triggered authentication, so to perform a second redirect?

Answer (score 3):

Storing temporary post in session isn't good idea, session is stored in cookies, so it's just size-limited. Most probably you will need to store it to DB (with some flag ie. `unauthicated: true`) and in session store only id of the temporary post and eventually some unique token. So after authentication you can get these values from session and use redirect which allow to further edit and final publication after login.

In such case I'd recommend also to use some scheduler which will clear not-confirmed posts after several hours/days.

On the other hand allowing unauthenticated/unknown users to fill up Post form and storing it in DB (especially if the Post model is large and/or allows ie. for adding files) isn't good idea as it brings a risk of spamming and DoS attacks, so maybe it will be just easier to require authentication before form sending (ajax?) like it's done ie. in comments systems like **disqus** or **livefyre**.

Comment: +1 for Ajax: try and submit the form data in Ajax. If this fails because the user is not authenticated or his sesion timed out, authenticate him using Ajax, then retry sending the data. The client never leaves the page where the data is sent from, so there is no need to implement custom data storage or post-login redirect system.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question!
As biesior said, the best would be to force authentication before form submission.

If you can't, don't put your data in the session as it's limited in size (or only if your data are very small) and is signed... Actually session cookies aren't meant for this!
So you must submit your post data to the server, store them in cache (or DB as biesior said) with a custom ID and redirect to the authenticator with this ID in the query (or session cookie) and when it is redirected back to your server, you can re-find the data from the ID and finalize the POST.

Comment: her I am talking about form (like a message,or a post ! ) information, not about the auth information! maybe my question was unclear, I have edited it making a blog post example